How to use BNO055 via HIT over i2c
We are using the Arduino Nano board and connected the Bno055 sensor to it via HID over I2C (hereinafter simply HIT). For the purposes of the academic project, we need to figure out how to program the sensor via this interface, not via the usual I2C.
There is very little information about this on the Internet. The most popular Adafruit library for this sensor, as I understand it, does not support HIT. I have not found a single library that supports this interface.
We also found out that the standard Wire library for I2C does not support HIT either. We will be grateful for any help.

Sounds like you choose a wrong MCU (Arduino Nano doesn't have a USB/HID peripheral) and a wrong sensor. Maybe you should clarify with your teacher. If you are interested on the I2C HID, you can take a look at those Hackaday blogs here and here, or the Linux source code.

@hcheung, You didn't quite understand what I meant. If only the PS0 jumper is connected to the ground, then the BNO055 sensor, according to the BOSCH documentation, operates via the HID over I2C interface. Then its address is 0x40. How do I work with this address?

To be clear, you want to operate it in HID over I2C mode (PS1=0;PS0=1) despite the fact that it will be significantly easier for you to use in the more conventional I2C mode (PS1=0;PS0=0)?

here is more information https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-use-bno055-via-hit-over-i2c/1336233 ... it appears that the OP has been tasked to write a driver

I'm not aware of any Arduino libraries or tutorials to do HID over I2C. I was curious enough to learn quite a lot about it from the ground up about 9 months ago. It's just too involved to want to turn into an answer on here. You'd need the main documentation to HID over I2C. This will only make sense in light of an understanding of the normal USB HID, HID usage tables, etc. It is also rather pointless and painful to choose it over the normal register-based I2C BNO055 interface without good reason.

@jsotola, I am the author of this post

@timemage, This is the goal of the project
